# How to create parameters in Express router dynamically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, express-router

Existing Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/data/:d1/:d2/:d3', require('../apifoo').foo);

Route:
/data/:d1/:d2/:d3

Path:
/data/1/2/3

req.params :
'd1' :'1',
'd2': '2',
'd3': '3'
```

---

But what if the number of parameters is not known in advance? I tried to define these parameters dynamically by means of regular expression::

```
router.get(/\/data(\/\d+){1,}$/, require('../apifoo').foo);

RegExp:
/\/data(\/\d+){1,}$/

Path:
/data/1/2/3

req.params :
'0' : '/3'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work! Is it possible to obtain the same 'req.params' like in example above, using RegExp or somewhat else?

Comment: no errors at all

Comment: I just don't quite understand: is it limitation of the express-router itself or there is an error in the regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define specific route for handling request what you can do is you can make the param optional like below

```
router.get('/data/:d1?/:d2?/:d3?', require('../apifoo').foo);
```

so this route will work in case of /data/1 and in case of /data/1/2 and also in case of /data/1/2/3

Regex in route is only for restricting routes to accept params in certain format for more information visit this url https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html